# git clone via git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git in company network

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I added my public key to github and tried to clone with

```
git clone git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git
```

and

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git
```

on my **private** computer in the git bash. Everything works fine, but on my computer, connected to the **company network** I'm only able to clone via https in the git bash. For ssh I got following error

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I checked the ~/.ssh folder and I think everything is correct. I also tried

```
git clone git@192.30.255.112:xxx/yyy.git
```

without success. Also searched in other forums/questions without success.

Does somebody know a solution/workaround this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generate a ssh key and add it to Github. https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

But if your company is using a proxy you need to tell git about that with that command: `git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:'proxypassword'@proxy.server.com:port`

Comment: As mentioned in the above question I added the ssh key to github.

Comment: git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:'proxypassword'@proxy.server.com:port

didn't resolve the problem. Still the same error